# How to insert 1 Billion rows in google-bigquery?

Tags: sorting, google-bigquery, sql-insert, database-performance

I need to insert 1 billion rows in Google bigquery table. But I don't have the data readily available.

I will have to make several millions of asynchronous http requests(1 asynchronous request = 1000 rows of ordered data). Each row has a column called `ID` and I need the billion rows in bigquery table ordered by ID once all requests are completed because it is timeseries data.

Challenge is, asynchronous calls doesn't have any order.(Also I will use parallelization across multiple CPUs). If I insert rows as they come and wait till all the billion are inserted, I am afraid sorting billion rows might take lot of time at the end.

One naïve way is to create the `ID` column with billion integers before hand, create empty columns for other fields and insert data by searching the `ID`, which I think is also inefficient.

Is there an efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: i think you fall into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/507852)

Comment: May be, but aren't my concerns valid? If it wasn't for the size of problem, I wouldn't have bothered posting here.

Comment: I can be wrong but - I feel like your concern is not BigQuery-compatible! Looks like you want to rely on physical order of the rows in the table  - but that is not how it works. There is no physical order here and no indexes, etc. ...